# Prevent get_object from hitting DB multiple times in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Question is about getting  get_object method in `DRF`.

Thing is when I need to get object in view or in serializer via serializer contex, each time I call `get_object` it sends new set of queries to DB and this is not acceptable as this behavior puts overhead on DB. Seems like DRF does not cache    `get_object`  result at all or does not save it in instance as well, at least I haven’t found any tracks of this in source code.

In order to not send same queries to DB multiple times I do following:

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = super().get_object()
    setattr(self, 'obj', obj)
    return obj
```

And then use `self.obj` in my code lately when I need it.
From my point of view doing so in each and every generic DRF view class where I need to use `get_object` more the onсe – it’s kind of something is really wrong. Either my logic or DRF source code.
Realistically  first assumption has more odds to be true.

Question is -what is wrong in my approach in saving  `get_object` result in attribute and if its any more generic or pythonic way to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is why do you need to call `get_object()` that often? You usually shouldn't need to invoke that function yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check your cached object first, then if it doesn't exist, you set the attribute.

You wouldn't need to use self.obj directly because you have customised your get_object method to return the object directly if it's set.

Also, the setup of self.obj depends on the get_object() to set itself at the first place, using get_object() along the way would make it consistent with other DRF methods.

```py
def get_object(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'obj'):
        return self.obj
    obj = super().get_object()
    setattr(self, 'obj', obj)
    return obj
```

However, using the cached object directly would mean that you get rid of the object permission checking in later communications [based on the source code of get_object](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/fccfdd21c078579bb0029db7289d5e19d58201e8/docs/api-guide/generic-views.md#get_objectself). If a user's permission has changed in the middle of the procedure, your view would return the results while the user has been revoked its permission.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer this method,

```
class MyViewClass(...):
    _object = None

    def get_object(self):
        if self._object is None:
            self._object = super().get_object()
        return self._object
```

Also, I would use **`self.get_object()`** method wherever I want instead of **`self._object`** attribute since `self._object` can be `None` sometimes

Comment: Any particular reason you store the `_object` as a class attribute instead of an instance attribute?